Why is this proof of the Tarski-Vaught criterion incorrect?
The Tarski-Vaught test states that if $N \subseteq M$ are $L$-structures, such that for every $L$-formula $\varphi(x, a_1, \ldots , a_n)$ with parameters $a_1, \ldots , a_n \in N$ we have $M \models \exists x \varphi(x, a_1, \ldots , a_n) \Longrightarrow N \models \exists x \varphi(x, a_1, \ldots , a_n)$, then $N \preceq M$.
This is usually proven using induction over all formulas, but I was wondering what's wrong with the following argument: To prove $N \preceq M$ it is enough to show that if $M \models \psi(a_1, \ldots , a_n)$ for some $L$-formula with parameters $a_1, \ldots , a_n$, then $N \models \psi(a_1, \ldots , a_n)$. Now let us simply define $\varphi(x, a_1, \ldots , a_n) =  \psi(a_1, \ldots , a_n) \land (x=x)$. Then the statement $\exists x \varphi(x, a_1, \ldots , a_n)$ is of course true in $M$, and by the Tarski-Vaught criterion also in $N$, which implies $N \models \psi(a_1, \ldots , a_n)$.
I am assuming there is some flaw in this silly argument. It is just confusing to me that in the criterion, the formula $\varphi$ is arbitrary, and not quantifier-free or otherwise restricted, so I don't see a where my proof could be wrong.

No issues with the proof. The problem is you are proving the wrong thing: the statement you have written is not the Tarski-Vaught criterion.
The Tarski-Vaught criterion is the more useful statement that if, for any formula $\varphi(x)$ with parameters in $N$, the existence of an $m\in M$ such that $M\models \varphi(m)$ implies the existence of an $n\in N$ such that $M\models \varphi(n)$, then we have $N\preceq M.$ Notice the criterion makes no reference to truth in $N$.

Thank you, I knew I must have been confused somewhere.
